# deleting all not latin characters in R

Tags: r, string, tm

here two strings

```
*3472459 PIVO 何か-何か-何か/100х1,5g

*3472459 VINO 何か何か何か100х1,5g
```

How to deleting all not latin characters? 
 output should be

```
PIVO
Vino
```

Comment: do you want to remove the japanese characters? Or only keep pivo / vino (Polish?) Because removing all non latin chars would leave you with "*3472459 PIVO /100х1,5g"

Comment: @phiver characters can be japanese, cyrillic and so on. latin can be polish, english.... . ideally leave pure words without numbers and letters denoting a measure (g is gram), if it impossible, let be simple so. "*3472459 PIVO /100х1,5g"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

given the text string in text, `str_extract` from stringr or `stri_extract` from stringi returns the expected result.

```
text <- c("*3472459 PIVO 何か-何か-何か/100х1,5g",
          "*3472459 VINO 何か何か何か100х1,5g")

stringr::str_extract(text, "[:alpha:]+")
[1] "PIVO" "VINO"

stringi::stri_extract(text, regex = "[:alpha:]+")
[1] "PIVO" "VINO"
```